# Creating Date by iso ''0001-01-01T01:00:00' adding 16 second

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone-offset

`new Date("0001-01-01T01:00:00Z")` --> `Mon Jan 01 0001 02:50:16 GMT+0150 (Moscow Standard Time)`
Incorrect GMT: my timezone `GMT+3000`, but date creates `GMT+0150`

Comment: The "GMT+0150" is a display issue with the toString() method (or when you just do a `console.log`  in your browser). The internal datetime reprentation is the same for javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: The "GMT+0150" is't a display issue, because getTimezoneOffset() returns incorrect  value

Comment: Since you haven't provided an explicit timezone, the timezone offset is inferred by your locale settings. (note: the date in javascript are notoriously hard to work with, especially with these timezones  / offset problems)

Comment: I really doubt any country on earth had time zones already in the year 1 A.D., so I wonder what’s the point of this exercise anyway …? Bet you get a different result if you start this with something like `new Date("2001-…`

Comment: @04FS Indeed, I used 1990 year in my example. Note that there are somehow retroactive definitions for IANA timezones  / offsets for those years, but they might not make sense depending on the application. For instance, Asia/Jerusalem will give me an offset of +2:20:41, probably set as a "default value" by IANA rules and inferred by the position of the sun, but I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: If you need to rely on `getTimezoneOffset()`, I think it would be better to reformulate your question with the actual goal you are trying to achieve. It will enable other answers maybe more useful for your actual usecase.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849404

Comment: @LinaGurinovich About the 16 seconds, I added something about that to my answer. This is not a problem of parsing, again, only of timezone offset "definitions" for those years. When some committee normalized timezone, this was about recently. They tried to establish some rules to get something meaningful (kinda) for the previous years. Basically, they used some calculations depending on solar time, which is why it doesn't give nice round numbers. This is all fixed convention, and it may or may not fit your application. Do you actually need those 0001 years ?

Comment: for additional advice, I recommend that you give an eye on the widely uses "moment.js" library. (But it is good to know about the "pure JS" date system, of course)

Answer (score 2):

For dates, you can (and should, in my opinion) define them in UTC ISO 8601 "Z" format ("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"), just as you did.

However, to get a *user-friendly string representation* of those dates, it will depend on your client and on the Javascript engine used. You can constrain the output if you explicitly specify a reference timezone with `toLocaleString()`.

```js
    var date = new Date("1990-01-01T01:00:00Z");

    console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Jerusalem"}));
    console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Europe/Moscow"}));
    console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Africa/Djibouti"}));
    // output on my machine, should be the same on yours : 
    // 1/1/1990, 3:00:00 AM
    // 1/1/1990, 4:00:00 AM
    // 1/1/1990, 4:00:00 AM

    console.log(date.toString());
    // output **on my machine**, should **not** be the same on yours
    // Mon Jan 01 1990 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

---

For the **16 seconds** issue, this is linked to the way offset are defined by the rules for those dates before the notion of IANA timezone existed.

They probably don't make sense in your application, and I discourage you to use dates like 1st January of year 0001 for your examples.

Examples :

```js
    var date = new Date("0001-01-01T01:00:00Z");

    console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Jerusalem"}));
    console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Europe/Moscow"}));
    console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Africa/Djibouti"}));
    // output on my machine, should be the same on yours : 
    // 1/1/1, 3:20:54 AM
    // 1/1/1, 3:30:17 AM
    // 1/1/1, 3:27:16 AM

    console.log(date.toString());
    // output **on my machine**, should **not** be the same on yours
    // Mon Jan 01 0001 01:09:21 GMT+0009 (Central European Standard Time)
```

---

More information here (thanks Johan Karlsson for the link) :

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849404

The most relevant comment from this link is, I think :

> This is working as intended and working per spec. The spec says that
>   we have to follow the IANA timezone database.
>
> In 1880, there's no standard timezone and America/Los_Angeles timezone
>   offset was based on its longitude. The same is true of other
>   timezones.
>
> Also note that there are many timezone around the world the zone
>   offset (and whether or not to have DST or when to start DST) have
>   changed multiple times even since 2000 (e.g. Europe/Moscow).  The
>   change to make them work correctly  also brought in what's reported
>   here.

Comment: added a bit more info, from the link Johan Karlsson gave on comments on your question.

Answer (score 2):

[Pac0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461643/creating-date-by-iso-0001-01-01t010000-adding-16-second/54461736#54461736) is correct (and you should accept that answer since it came first, not this one).  But just to provide a detailed explanation:

Dates from before recorded history of time zones are marked in [the time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) as `LMT` - which stands for [Local Mean Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time).  The offsets are derived from the latitude and longitude of the city, not by any current political determination.

Since the offset shown is `1:50:16` ahead of UTC, I can derive that your system time zone is `Europe/Minsk`.  This is seen [in the tzdb sources here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018i/europe#L866):

```
# Zone  NAME          GMTOFF   RULES  FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Europe/Minsk  1:50:16  -      LMT     1880
```

This is just the first line of the zone entry for `Europe/Minsk`, which says that until 1880, use the LMT entry of UTC+1:50:16.

As to why it says "Moscow Standard Time" - that string comes from the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) data, which in the [`/common/supplemental/metaZones.xml`](https://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/metaZones.xml) file we can see:

```xml
<timezone type="Europe/Minsk">
  <usesMetazone to="1991-03-30 23:00" mzone="Moscow"/>
  <usesMetazone to="2011-03-27 00:00" from="1991-03-30 23:00" mzone="Europe_Eastern"/>
  <usesMetazone to="2014-10-26 22:00" from="2011-03-27 00:00" mzone="Europe_Further_Eastern"/>
  <usesMetazone from="2014-10-26 22:00" mzone="Moscow"/>
</timezone>
```

So `Europe/Minsk` uses the `Moscow` metazone up until 1991.  Then, using one of the language files such as [`/common/main/en.xml`](https://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/main/en.xml) for English, we can see the actual text assigned to this metazone:

```xml
<metazone type="Moscow">
  <long>
    <generic>Moscow Time</generic>
    <standard>Moscow Standard Time</standard>
    <daylight>Moscow Summer Time</daylight>
  </long>
</metazone>
```

And now you have a complete picture for how the string `Mon Jan 01 0001 02:50:16 GMT+0150 (Moscow Standard Time)` was derived from `0001-01-01T01:00:00Z`.

Answer (score 1):

A timezone is an offset plus a date range. To format your date, javascript wants to know what the timezone offset was for Moscow in the year zero. This is hard information to come by, and might not be accurate ! You think you're asking something simple, but it's actually pretty extreme. If you want to use the date object to represent durations, you should take the epoch as your starting point.

Comment: Right. But even at epoch, you could be surprised as some countries have changed offset or Daylight Saving Time rules since then. For instance, to take an example related to OP's question, Russia has stopped using DST since 2010. Dates in summer won't have same UTC offset before 2010 or after.